# How do I convert a text file into a list while deleting duplicate words and sorting the list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to read lines in a file, split the lines into words, and add the individual words to a list if they are not already in the list. Lastly, the words have to be sorted. I've been trying to get this right for a while, and I understand the concepts, but I'm not sure how to get the exact language and placement right. Here's what I have:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
openedfile = open(filename)
lst = list()
for line in openedfile:
    line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
for word in words:
    if word not in lst:
        lst.append(words)
print lst
```

Comment: Is there just one word per line?

Comment: `for word in words` should be indented.

Comment: `lst.append(words)` <- whoops, you just appended the whole line (`words`) instead of the current word (`word`). Your call to `rstrip()` also has no effect since you're not taking its return value into account.

Comment: have a look at map and filter (optionally sub a comprehension for the filter)
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: if you want uniqueness, please for the love of O(1) use a set.

Comment: Store the words in a `set()`, which will automatically remove any duplicates. Afterwards, `lst = sorted(set_of_words)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're splitting the text file into words based on whitespace, just use `split()` on the whole thing. There's nothing to be gained by reading each line and stripping it, because `split()` already handles all that.

So to get the initial list of words, all you need is this:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
openedfile = open(filename)
wordlist = openedfile.read().split()
```

Then to remove duplicates, convert the word list to a set:

```
wordset = set(wordlist)
```

And finally sort it:

```
words = sorted(wordset)
```

This can all be simplified to three lines, like so:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(filename) as stream:
    words = sorted(set(stream.read().split()))
```

(NB: the `with` statement will automatically close the file for you)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you want

> lst.append(word)

to only append a word if not in the list already. You have    lst.append(words). That is wrong.

Second, to sort just use

> lst.sort()

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop for `for word in words:` when you do - `lst.append(words)` - it appends the whole `words` list into `lst` , I believe you intended to use - `lst.append(word)` .

Also, the for loop - `for word in words:` should be indented inside `for line in openedfile:` , so that you run the loop for each line.

And lastly, if you want to lexicographically sort the words, you should call - `lst.sort()` at the end.

Also, it would be better to use `with` statement to open the file, so that it can handle closing the file after everything is finish automatically.

Also, it may be easier to use `set()` as the initial data type to store the elements as the `not in` operator for `list` is O(n) , and as the list gets bigger, that would take more time. Whereas with a `set` data type, you do not need to worry about checking if the set already has the word, since set does not allow duplicates.

At the end, you can use `list(..)` to convert the set back to list and then sort it.

Example -

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(filename) as openedfile:
    s = set()
    for line in openedfile:
        line.rstrip()
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            s.update(words)
    lst = list(s)
    lst.sort()
    print lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Consider using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) for the words. Adding another word only really adds it when its not in there already.
2. Open the file with `'r'` to indicate read-only mode.
3. Sorting is really easy (also for `sets`), just use `sorted()`.

Something like this works:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")

words = set()
with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        new_words = line.strip().split(' ')
        words.update(new_words)

print sorted(words)
```